# Update querystring value in href with jQuery

Tags: jquery, query-string

I have 3 href's that have a different structure and all of them have the same hard coded parameter (in this example value=somevalue-abc).

How can I update the link and overwrite the value with a new value?

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a').click(function () {

        var $newValue = 'newvalue';

        //here a function that overwrites the parameter 'somevalue-abc' with $newValue

    });

});
```

HTML

```
<a class="demo" href="http://www.mydomain.com/page.aspx?demo&value=somevalue-abc">link 1</a>
<a class="real" href="http://www.mydomain.com/?value=somevalue-abc#go=yes">link 2</a>
<a class="outgoing" href="http://www.mydomain.com/page.aspx?value=somevalue-abc">link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var $newValue = 'newvalue';
        $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('somevalue-abc', $newValue));
    });
});
```

Comment: works perfect (and so simple I can shoot myself not finding this myself).
Thx!!

Answer (score 5):

```
$('a').click(function() {
  var newValue = 'newvalue'; // pls don't use a $ on variables that aren't jquery objects
  var src = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('href', src.replace(/somevalue\-abc/, newvalue));
});
```